# React fetch API won't return the result

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm having trouble trying to fetch API from this API https://gutendex.com/books/.

This is my code:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])
  const LoadData = async() =>{
    const value = await fetch('https://gutendex.com/books/');
    const res = await value.json()
    setData(res.results[0])

  }

  useEffect(() =>{
    LoadData()
  },[])


  return (
    <div className="App">
       <img src={data.formats.image/jpeg} alt={data.title}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The error it shows:

> ```
> data.formats is undefined
> ```

Then I try the return`{data.formats}` to see what happen.
It shows new error like this

> Error Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {application/x-mobipocket-ebook, application/epub+zip,
> application/rdf+xml, text/html; charset=utf-8, text/plain;
> charset=utf-8, image/jpeg, text/html}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Well, `data.formats` *is* `undefined`.  `data` is an array: `const [data, setData] = useState([])`  And an array has no property called `formats`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is rendered before the API call is complete. When this happens there is no data to display. Change you return statement to this:

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
       {data && (<img src={data.formats["image/jpeg"]} alt={data.title}/>)}
    </div>
  );
```

Also, the initial value of data shouldn't be an array, you should set this to null or undefined.

The image will be hidden until the API call is complete, and data

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe rearrange your function a bit. Instead of writing the function apart, write it in the useEffect. I know gunwin already gave the answer, but I am concentrating on the useEffect function. So here is the solution:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const loadData = async () => {
     await fetch('https://gutendex.com/books/')
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((data) => setData(data.results[0]))
     .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  }
}, []);
```

This should normally work, if not check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch